# Creating led sequence without microcontrollers

Tags: led, transistors

I'm new to electronics and I can work only with transistors. I'm trying to create a circuit that performs action like this: 
 
Let's say I have 10 LEDs. When I supply power first LED lights, 0.5 sec later second LED lights and 0.5 sec later third LED lights and so on. But all the LEDs keep lighting during others light. 
 
I want to know if it's possible or not. If possible please give a link to such a tutorial. 
 
Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible using 10 bit Johnson counter with 2 Hz clock frequency, but it repeats the cycle after the last LED turns on (10th bit).

---

[image: I added NAND gate(74LS00N) to the ckt for resetting all the states, when reaching the 10 bits are high,1 HZ signal can be generated by using 555 timer ckt]

Comment: repeating  the cycle after the last led is so good :) thanks for your answer! i will try it. But sorry i can't vote your answer up :(

Answer (score 6):

I would take a 555 square wave generator output from here [555 Oscillator Tutorial](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/555_oscillator.html) and drive shift register clock input from here [The Shift Register](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_5.html). Shift registers input should high all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer *I* personally use in my circuits:

Use a sawtooth voltage (i.e. from simple BJT sawtooth generator) and a ADC with LED driver (LM3914 comes to mind, can drive 10 LEDs, no resistors needed) - you only require 1 IC and LEDs to do the visual part, but you can easily change the behaviour of the LEDs by changing the voltage ramping (sine, tri) and frequency.

*Also, you'll get a fully functional ADC/VU meter/voltage meter in the meantime, free of charge.*